# WiFi Spectrum Analyzer for Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project for my final project at my school. I want to be able to detect interference on the 2.4 and 5 GHz spectrum.  I know this is possible with a spectrum analyzer. I know there is a lot of hardware out there, such as RTL-SDR, HackRF, PlutoSDR, but I just want to look at the 2.4 and 5 GHz frequencies.  I don't need to see other radio signals.

I'm trying to find a package I can install on a raspberry pi with an API that I can see the degradation or interference in code, that I can then create my own interface with.

I've seen `sparrow-wifi`, but this doesn't work on Raspberry Pi, only the agent does. I also don't see an API with that.

Are there some existing tools out there that I can do this with?

Comment: read the overview at https://github.com/ghostop14/sparrow-wifi